# Can't call explicitly destructor when object passed as reference

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have the following piece of code in main:

```
void *pmemory;
pmemory = malloc(ONEGIG_SIZE);
PoolAllocator* poolAllocator =  new PoolAllocator(sizeof(Obj), __alignof(Obj), ONEGIG_SIZE, pmemory);


Obj *obj1 = allocator::allocateNew(*poolAllocator, Obj("Temp"));
allocator::deallocateDelete(*poolAllocator, obj1);
```

And the code in the deallocateDelete() method is the following:

```
template<class T> void deallocateDelete(Allocator& allocator, T& object)
{
    object.~T();
    allocator.deallocate(&object);
}
```

I notice that if i pass the T object to the deallocateDelete() method as reference, the following line ( object.~T(); ) is not working, i mean the destructor is not called. But if i change the parameter to pointer T* object, then the destructor is called. Any one can explain me why is this happening ?

Comment: You call the destructor of the pointer (not the object it points too) and then call `deallocate` on the memory of the pointer (again not the object).

Comment: In `void deallocateDelete` the type `T` is `Obj*`. It looks like you expected it to be `Obj`.

Comment: You should *never* have a reason to call a destructor directly - except maybe in highly specialised code inside an alocator and/or when dealing with placement-new. All of which you should usually *never* have to deal with in most cases. Why are you doing this stuff at all?

Comment: @Jesper Juhl Because I am using placement-new , like this return new (allocator.allocate(sizeof(T), __alignof(T))) T(t);
    }

Comment: @MichaelBurr so i should pass the object as pointer to the deleteDeallocate method ?

Comment: @JesperJuhl *"except maybe in highly specialised code inside an alocator"* this appears to be precisely OP's situation.

Comment: @RoStel you **are** passing a pointer to the `deleteDeallocate` function. But the function appears to be written to expect a non-pointer instead.

Answer (score 0):

> i mean the destructor is not called

Actually, the destructor is technically called. It's just that the destructor of `T` is trivial, so its call cannot be observed.

I suspect that you think that `T` is `Obj`. But it's not: The object that you passed to the function is `Obj*` so the argument is deduced to be `Obj*&`.

To call `deallocateDelete` with a `Obj&` argument, you must dereference the pointer (just like you dereference the pointer to the allocator):

```
allocator::deallocateDelete(*poolAllocator, *obj1);
//                                          ^
```